# Htaccess redirect matching from a list?

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect

I believe there should be a simpler method to rewriting URLs than I currently have and wonder if anyone can help.

The site I am working on has multiple brands for example:

```
https://example.com/anything/brand/nike/something
https://example.com/anything/brand/puma/something
```

My current redirect would be

```
RedirectMatch 301 "(.*)/brand/nike(.*)$" "$1/manufacturer--nike"
```

To get me the following output, removing `/brand/` and replacing `nike` with `manufacturer--nike` and finally removing anything that follows i.e. `/something`.

```
https://example.com/anything/manufacturer--nike
```

Now I could add a second rule for `Puma` and each of the other brands, but I imagine there is a way to match against a list of brands and use one rule but my Google skills have failed me in finding a solution.

Is there a way?

Comment: A list of rules implementing specific tokens to match a URL against _is_ a list. There is no sense to replace one list with another ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the number of brands are limited then you could use *alternation* (eg. `nike|puma|brand` etc.) in the regex, to match `nike` or `puma` or `brand`.

*Aside:* To match `nike/<something>`, you should at least check for that slash, otherwise it's going to match `nikeeeee` and `nikey` etc. (Although not necessarily an issue.)

For example:

```
RedirectMatch 301 "(.*)/brand/(nike|puma|brand)/" "$1/manufacturer--$2"
```

The `(.*)$` at the end of the regex - to simply remove the trailing part of the URL-path - is not required.

The `$2` backreference contains the "brand-name" matched by the second capturing (alternation) subpattern.

> method to rewriting URLs

Just to clarify, this is an *external redirect*, it's not "rewriting URLs".

Comment: Many thanks. You're right about checking for the slash and that solution I think will work perfectly.